# Change content of span by id

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I am trying to change john to mike. I have no idea why its not working.

```
<span id="user">John</span>
```

I am trying this but not working i have no clue why not working.

```
function set() {
    document['getElementById']('user')['value'] = Owner; 
    // owner value is mike
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `span` tag has a value?

Comment: Why don't you use the `obj.key` syntax instead of `obj['key']`? For static keys that's the way to go. Nobody expects `document['getElementById']` instead of `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to change the id, use

```
 document['getElementById']('user').id = 'mike';
```

or, more classically,

```
 document.getElementById('user').id = 'mike';
```

If you want to replace "John" (that is not the ID but the content of the span), do

```
 document.getElementById('user').innerHTML = 'mike';
```

Comment: How changing `id` may change the node's text?

Comment: @zerkms Question title ("trying to change span id") and question content are different. That's why I provided a solution for each.

Answer (score 3):

```
function set() {
    document.getElementByID('user').innerHTML = Owner; 
    // owner value is mike
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
function set() {
    document.getElementById('user').innerText= Owner; 
    // owner value is mike
}
```

Where is `Owner` declared, is it valid in your function scope?

Comment: innerText is IE specific. It's now supported by Chrome but not Firefox.

Comment: To be fair... that's not obvious. And the use of the textContent name by other browsers doesn't help.

Comment: that's why I use jQuery, to abstract away browser specific stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
function set()
{
  var elem = document.getElementById('user'); 

  elem.innerHTML = "Owner";
}

if you want to add an **id** you can use **setAttribute()**
eg:

 document.getElementById('user').setAttribute('id','owner');
```

**Note**

```
 **value** attribute only work with input, text area,button etc..
```

eg:

```
 <input type="text" id="inid" value=""/>

 document.getElementById('inid').value = "Something";  // this will work
```

Answer (score 1):

For modern Browsers

```
document.getElementById("span_id_here").textContent="yourtext";
```